# Spring Boot Security + Data Jpa + Auditing

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

У меня общий вопрос.

Готовлю CRUD приложение.

Сущности в БД расширяются от `Auditable<U>`.
Security авторизует пользователя и в БД попадают записи о пользователе, произведшим действия.

Мне нужно организовать доступ к записям в БД, которые принадлежат только зарегистрированному пользователю. Как это лучше сделать?

Во всех CRUD действиях производить проверку типа

```
 - findAllByUsername(String username);
 - findByUsernameAndItemId(String username,Long itemId);
 - перед save и update чекать вручную, принадлежат-ли пользователю эти записи?
и т.п.?
```

или есть какой-то паттерн на этот случай?

Comment: Это делает слой бизнес логики. Или же слой сервисов.

Comment: ну т.е. каких либо аннотаций на эту тему нет, просто написать какой-то промежуточный сервис?

Comment: Что значит промежуточный? вся логика пишется в сервисе. Запрос приходит на контроллер, контроллер передает полученные данные в сервис. Сервис чет делает и отдает ответ.

Comment: все верно, просто контроллеров много и сервисы у каждого свой. А проверку принадлежности пользователей и данных хочется вынести в один сервис для всех, чтоб в одном месте было...

Comment: Каких данных? уточните пожалуйста

Comment: Данных в бд, которые принадлежат пользователю.

Comment: Хочется красивое решение. Чтоб сервис оставался простым CRUD. Может на уровень репозитория спустить добавление в запросы к базе, проверку прав или ролей пользователя на запрашиваемые данные?

Comment: Хотя это из простого jparepository интерфейса придется делать класс...